# NSXMLParser problem with "&"(Ampersand) character

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser, nsxml

My NSXMLParsing is not working because of "&" character.. my code s below .any help please ?

```
 NSString *myRequestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://abc.com/def/webservices/aa.php?family_id=%d",self.passFamilyId];
//NSLog(@"Requested Service = %@",myRequestString);
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myRequestString]];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST" ];
NSData *downloadedData = [ NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloadedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
//NSString *contentString = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
NSData * data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];


//NSLog (@"string is :%@" ,str);    

NSXMLParser *xmlParser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];   

// Call the XMLParsers's initXMLParse method.
ClientDetailXmlParser *parser = (ClientDetailXmlParser*)[[ClientDetailXmlParser alloc] initXMLParser];
[xmlParser setDelegate:parser];
BOOL success = [xmlParser parse];

// Check for XML parsing.
if(success) 
{
    NSLog(@"No Errors in clientDetailXml.xml");     
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"Error Error Error in clientDetailXml.xml!!!");
}   

[parser release];
parser = nil;

if (objClientAddUpdate != nil) {
    [objClientAddUpdate createBubbleList];
}
```

Comment: Does it work when you replace "&" with "&amp;"?

Comment: No it cant i tried it.can you change my code i have not idea..i dont know how which string should be replaced in my code..

Comment: Modify your clientDetailXml.xml file and replace the & to 'and'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloadedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
//NSString *contentString = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
NSData * data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

With:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloadedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *contentString = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
NSData * data=[contentString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: This method is not a solution in case the string has escaped ampersand (&amp;). So it seems more appropriate to use a regular expression to find unescaped ampersand only.

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to sepehr-mahmoudian's answer, but instead of replace any & you should really just replace & characters that are unescaped, to do this you can use a regexp:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloadedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
//NSString *contentString = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
NSData * data=[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

With:

```
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:downloadedData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSRange searchedRange = NSMakeRange(0, [str length]);
NSString *pattern = @"&(?!(#[0-9]{2,4}|[A-z]{2,6});)";
NSError *error = nil;

NSRegularExpression* regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern options:0 error:&error];
str = [regex stringByReplacingMatchesInString:str options:0 range:searchedRange withTemplate:@"&amp;"];

NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's what worked for me:

```
NSString *response = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:dataResponse encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSString *newResponse = [response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&amp:" withString:@"AND"];
NSData *dataObj = [newResponse dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

If I replaced it with symbol '&', the response would be correct, but it would throw parsing error: 68. So I had to use 'and'.

Comment: Much of the time the & is not just literal but part of a URL or other instruction so this could potentially break things. It's better to escape the content in a way that will keep its meaning intact.