# NSXML Parsing Ampersand Character Causes Shut Down

Tags: objective-c, xml, parsing, nsstring, ampersand

I am parsing a simple XML file, however sometimes there are tags that contain ampersands (&) in the node. I've done some research [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838708/how-to-parse-strings-containing-ampersands-with-nsxmlparser) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291534/nsxmlparser-problem-with-ampersand-character) but the problem is persisting. The problem is that the parser simply stops when it encounters the offending XML element. The XML looks like this:

```
<video>
  <video_id>42</video_id>
  <video_header>Six & Eight</video_header>
  <video_subheader>So Long</video_subheader>
</video>
```

The parser is updating an object, called `DisStep`, that has a `parsedVideoArray` attribute. The attribute is just an array of `Parsed_Video` objects. So the problem would be that when the the parser gets to `foundCharacters` for the element `video_header` it will not continue to `didEndElement`. In fact, an `NSLog` in the foundCharacters method of `currentNodeContent` is just `"Six "`.

And here is the code for the parser. All it does is look for videos and gather info about them.

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
  attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"video"])
    {
        videoBeingParsed = [[Parsed_Video alloc] init];
    }
}

-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) string;
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI
  qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"video_id"])
    {
        videoBeingParsed.Video_ID = currentNodeContent;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"video_header"])
    {
        videoBeingParsed.Video_Header = currentNodeContent;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }

    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"video_subheader"])
    {
        videoBeingParsed.Video_SubHeader = currentNodeContent;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
    else if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"video"])
    {
        [DisStep.parsedVideoArray addObject:videoBeingParsed];
        currentNodeContent = nil;
        videoBeingParsed = nil;
    }
}
@end
```

I tried the `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: withString:` but the parser still stops working. Is there a way around this other than changing the XML?

Comment: Before feeding the data to the parser, encode the ampersand.

Comment: How do you encode the ampersand from the data? Does that mean altering the XML or is it possible to do it programmatically in the parser?

Comment: @Jeremy sorry forgot to tag...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you have not been given XML and the parser legitimately gets in a mess as it sees data that is not legal.. The [XML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xml11-20060816/#syntax) says

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) must not appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they must be escaped using either numeric character references or the strings `"&amp;"` and `"&lt;"` respectively.

Thus you have to alter the XML and replace & by `&amp;`

Comment: Is there a way to alter the XML programmatically? Like as the parser loads the data have it change all instances of `&` to `&amp;`?

Comment: No as it deals with XMl and you have not got XML you have to alter the text or better as Michael Key says tell your supplier they have a bug that they must fix

Answer (score 0):

XML parsers are REQUIRED to report a fatal error when you give them input that isn't well-formed XML.

Find out what program generated this corrupt data and fix it.